# Using htaccess and mod_rewrite to display new-page instead of newpage

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm working on my website and I created a few new web pages that explains more details of my website. Now for seo purposes I know google prefers for the link to contain the key words. So the pages I'm making could be call new shoes. Now I have gotten the pages to work as website.com/newshoes but since google may view this as one word, I'm working on making it display website.com/new-shoes instead using htaccess but I can't get it to work. This is what I came up with but it didn't work.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)-([^/]*)$ /index.php?$1$2 [QSA,L]
```

So yeah can anyone help me out here. Thanks!

[edit]

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^reflap\.com [NC]

RewriteRule (.*) http://www.reflap.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /index.php?$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?$1&$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?$1&$2 [QSA,L]


RewriteRule ^/facebook-chat/ http://chat.facebook.com/ [P]

ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
```

Comment: How do you check that it doesn't work?

Comment: I tried to go to website.com/new-page and it didn't work.

Comment: what "didn't work" means? Did it output an exact label "I don't work" or what?

Comment: My website uses an MVC framework whereby whenever I pass a query if there is a controller for that query it will return the view page. If there is not controller for that query it redirects the user to the home page. That's what happened.

Comment: Try to enable mod_rewrite debug logging.

Comment: @Michael Nana: And if you request `website.com/index.php?newpage` it does work?

Comment: @Michael Nana: so how is it relevant to mod_rewrite then? You're rewriting a url to another url that doesn't work and wondering that it doesn't work. Are you sure the final url should be `/index.php?$1$2`?

Comment: The page in the server is website.com/newpage however I wdon't want website.com/newpage to display in the address bar, I want the address bar to display website.com/new-page instead. So if a person types website.com/new-page it should display the page in the directory website.com/newpage.

Comment: @Michael Nana: right. But do you realize you're rewriting to `/index.php?newpage` not to `/newpage`? Why do you add `index.php?` if you don't need it?

Comment: Well yeah exactly typing  website.com/new-page should display the /index.php?newpage page. That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: I need index.php It's the start of the mvc framweork and it's the page that includes all the controllers, views, models etc.

Comment: @Michael Nana: so what is your question now then? mod_rewrite works fine, but as you said before `website.com/index.php?newpage` is broken. What do you need from us?

Comment: No. I don't understand what your saying. This is what I have right now. website.com/newpage WORKS.No problem. If someone does website.com/newpage that will work. However if someone does website.com/new-page that won't work because there is no page on the server that is called new-page. However for seo purposes I want it such that when someone types website.com/new-page, the page loaded is website/newpage however in the address bar it says website.com/new-page.  Does that make more sense?

Comment: @Michael Nana: *sigh*. Let's start from the beginning: does `/index.php?newpage` url work as expected?

Comment: No. I don't understand what your saying. This is what I have right now. website.com/newpage WORKS.No problem. If someone does website.com/newpage that will work. However if someone does website.com/new-page that won't work because there is no page on the server that is called new-page. However for seo purposes I want it such that when someone types website.com/new-page, the page loaded is website/newpage however in the address bar it says website.com/new-page. Does that make more sense?

Comment: @Michael Nana: please read the following **carefully**: **WHY** did you put the `/index.php?$1$2` part to the `RewriteRule`? Do you realize what it means?

Comment: I'm not super versed with rewriterules but I know that ([^/]*) =$1 and ([^/]*)=$2 and they are separated with a - to indicate what I was saying earlier.  So I was thing /index.php?$1$2 while concatenate the first bracket contents with the second bracket contents as in new =$1 and page=$2 becoming newpage. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Michael Nana: yep, it concatenates two parts and puts it **after** `index.php?` string. So **WHY** did you put `index.php?` there? Why `index.php?` not `someotherrandomstring`?

Comment: My whole website happens in index.php. The framework makes it that every page in the directory is included in the index.php so if you go to website.com/about index.php sends out the about controller which will then do include(about.php) in the index.

Comment: @Michael Nana: omg, you must be kidding. Dude, you want `website.com/new-page` to be rewritten to `website.com/newpage`. Do you see any `index.php?` in the latter? If you don't see it (I hope you don't) - why do you put it in rewrite rule?

Comment: I already have this rule in my htaccess RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?$1 [QSA,L]  which directs website.com to website.com/index.php

Comment: @Michael Nana: I hope you just had sleepless night and now cannot think fast. `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)-([^/]*)$ /$1$2 [QSA,L]` -- compare to what you have in the original question. Thoughts?

Comment: Nah it doesn't work either.

Comment: @Michael Nana: did you put it before any other rules? PS: do you now realize what I was hinting to for more than one hour?

Comment: This rule RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /index.php?$1 [QSA,L] is before this rule RewriteRule ^([^/]*)-([^/]*)$ /index.php?$1$2 [QSA,L]

Comment: No I don't realize what you have been hinting. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Michael Nana: it should be before, because order makes sense. The second rule isn't processed after the first is

Comment: @Michael Nana: I will try, for another time. Well: If you want to rewrite `website.com/new-page` url to `website.com/newpage` then you must rewrite it to `/newpage`. Not to `index?newpage` not to `omganotherfile.php?newpage`. But to `/newpage`. So in rewrite rule the second argument should rewrite to **EXACTLY WHAT YOU NEED**. Is it clear?

Comment: Yeah so this. RewriteRule ^([^/]*)-([^/]*)$ /$1$2 [QSA,L]     It doesn't work.

Comment: @Michael Nana: is it the first in the list of rules?

Comment: Nope. It's after RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: @Michael Nana: I have said **TWICE** (1: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705484/using-htaccess-and-mod-rewrite-to-display-new-page-instead-of-newpage#comment24048626_16705484, 2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705484/using-htaccess-and-mod-rewrite-to-display-new-page-instead-of-newpage#comment24048807_16705484) it should be before it

Comment: I tried it before and it actually gave me a 500 internal server error which makes sense.

Comment: This rule has to be the first RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?$1 [QSA,L]   It sets up the whole website.

Comment: @Michael Nana: no it shouldn't be the first. If it is the first then other rules don't have chance to affect on the rewriting process. And order or rules cannot make 500 error. If there is 500 it makes you've made a syntax error. Provide your whole `.htaccess` and show where you put your new rule

Comment: Put it to the question so that it was readable

Comment: Just added it to the question.

Comment: 1. where is the new rule? 2. `rewritecond` is tied to the following `rewriterule`. You have couple of rules that are affected by rewritecond and couple that aren't. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: The new rule I made was placed above the facebook chat rule. 2. Yeah, because newpage.php is not placed in the root it's placed in the folder called views.

Comment: It should be **BEFORE** other rules 2. You didn't get what I mean, perhaps because you don't know what `RewriteCond` is for

Comment: Ping me in Skype: zerkms, since I'm still keen to help but only if you understand what and why you're doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)-([^/]*)$ /index.php?$1$2

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^reflap\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.reflap.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ /index.php?$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /index.php?$1&$2 [QSA,L]


RewriteRule ^/facebook-chat/ http://chat.facebook.com/ [P]

ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put specifics in your rewrite rules above your generics - the ordering you have means that you are being redirected to index.php?new-page because you are matching a more general pattern first.

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^reflap\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.reflap.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)-([^/]*)$ /index.php?$1$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?$1&$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?$1&$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^/facebook-chat/ http://chat.facebook.com/ [P]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /index.php?$1 [QSA,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
```

This should fix your problem - but there's a more general issue in this .htaccess - `RewriteCond` directives only apply to the `RewriteRule` immediately following them. They don't continue on to any other rule following. This means that all rules after the first one will apply regardless of if the file or directory really exists.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond